# Total Commander go to directory

Tags: total-commander

For my Button Bar I would like to add an Icon that would take me to a specific directory. I've added command:

CD
with a specific path "C:..etc\

However this opens the directory on the opposite Pane instead of the pane my cursor is currently on.

EDIT:
[image]
So even though I place cursor on the right pane and click "VirtualBox" button it opens the directory in the left pane (instead of right where my cursor was)
please help
thanks

Comment: May you disclose a full path/command or even a button settings screen-shoot? It is working for me.

Comment: added image. hopefully that helps

Comment: Try "cd \\10.10.111.106" in Command with Start Path empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move a path to "Command" edit box:

```
CD \\10.10.111.106
```

and leave "Start path" edit box empty.